# How to write a regex to extract a number from these URLs?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match the numbers in these URLs (`12345678` and `1234567890`).

```
http://www.example.com/p/12345678
http://www.example.com/p/12345678?foo=bar
http://www.example.com/p/some-text-123/1234567890?foo=bar
```

Rules:

- the numbers always come after a slash
- the numbers can be varying lengths
- the regex must check that the URLs have `/p/` in them
- the numbers may be at the end of the URL, or there could be variables after them

My attempt:

```
\/p\/([0-9]+)
```

That matches the first and second, but not the third. So I tried:

```
\/p\/[^\/?]*\/?([0-9]+)
```

No joy.

[REGEX 101](https://regex101.com/r/pW5qB3/1)

Comment: What regex engine are you going to be using this in (what programming language?)

Comment: "\/[^\d]"? or even just "[^\d]" OR "[^\d+]" would do the trick I believe?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski PHP

Comment: Your first attempt does indeed match the second example (not the 3rd)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for the catch - that's what I get for reading too carelessly.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex might not be the right tool for this job.  It looks like in every case, splitting the URL with a URL parser would make more sense.  From your examples, it appears that the number portion is always the last item in the path portion of the URL.  I'm not sure what language you're using, but many languages offer functions that can parse URLs into their constituent parts.

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
if(strpos($path, "/p/") === 0) {
    $base = basename($path);
} else {
    // error
}
```

Works every time, assuming $url is the string you are parsing.

Comment: edited to remove a redundant call to `parse_url`.  `$path` can be passed to basename instead of calling `parse_url` again.

Answer (score 1):

I extended your version, it now works with all examples:

```
\/p\/(.+\/)*(\d+)(\?.+=.+(&.+=.+)*)?$
```

If you don't care that the URL is valid, you could shrink the regex to:

```
\/p\/(.+\/)*(\d+)($|\?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/pW5qB3/2

Comment: All the stuff at the end is not really necessary, since it's only the `/p/` and `\d+` that matter here.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski but the OP mentioned that the number should be the last part of the url, only arguments might follow, so this makes sure the url is valid and only parameters come after the number

Comment: Indeed that's true. You could just follow it with `($|\?)` so either a query string or the end of the string comes next. Not necessary to express the `key=value&key=value`

Comment: @DomStepek this would also match /sth/psth/sth/1234567890

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, the digits you want can only be:

- right after the last slash of the URL
- cannot be part of the variables, ie `/p/123?foo=bar456` matches `123` and
  `/p/foobar?foo=bar456` matches nothing

You can then use the following regex:

```
(?=/p/).*/\K\d+
```

**Explanation**

```
(?=/p/)  # lookahead: check '/p/' is in the URL
.*/      # go to the last '/' thanks to greediness
\K       # leave everything we have so far out of the final match
\d+      # select the digits just after the last '/'
```

To avoid escaping forward slashes don't use them as [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php): `#(?=/p/).*/\K\d+#` will do fine.

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pW5qB3/4).

Answer (score 0):

```
\/p\/(?:.*\/)?(\d+)\b
```

You can try this.This will capture integers based on your coditons.See demo.Grab the capture or group.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/29

```
$re = "/\\/p\\/(?:.*\\/)?(\\d+)\\b/";
$str = "http://www.example.com/p/12345678\nhttp://www.example.com/p/12345678?foo=bar\nhttp://www.example.com/p/some-text-123/1234567890?foo=bar";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"/(?<ticket>\d+)");

var subject = "http://www.example.com/p/some-text-123/1234567890?foo=bar";

var ticket = regex.Match(subject).Groups["ticket"].Value;
```

Output: 1234567890

Comment: This will match URLs which do not include `/p/`, which is required.